# Kann ß durch das griechische Beta β ersetzt werden?

Tags: eszett, typography

Ich habe eine Nachricht mit dem Wort

> **genieβen** (anstatt **genießen**)

bekommen. Es stört mich irgendwie genau so wie *oe* anstelle *ö*; nun weiß ich aber nicht, ob ich intolerant bin und lernen muss, diese Schreibweise zu akzeptieren, oder ob es tatsächlich ein Fehler ist. Ist das Beta geläufig?

Comment: Ich sehe diesen Fehler insbesondere bei naturwissenschaftlichen Ausdrücken manchmal andersherum, also dass statt β fälschlicherweise ein ß geschrieben wird.

Comment: In diesen typischen Bedienungsanleitungen für irgendwelche Billigprodukte aus dem Fernen Osten sieht man ein Beta verhältnismäßig oft. Sie bieten sich aber nicht gerade als Vorbild an. :-)

Comment: @c.p.: Ich meinte nicht, daß „dein“ Text eine solche Bedienungsanleitung sei. Es war nur ein Beispiel, wo man dem Phänomen sonst noch begegnet.

Comment: Trotz grösseren Aufwands: Falsch, und damit schlechter als das eigentlich einfachere *ss*. Aber immer noch besser, als am (US)-Traktor meiner Eltern in den 70ern, der ein Schild hatte, auf dem stand: *FuB vom Kupplungspedal nehmen*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Natürlich nicht. Im Deutschen nutzen wir keine griechischen Buchstaben, so ähnlich sie irgendwelchen anderen lateinischen Buchstaben aussehen mögen. Das Eszett entstand als Ligatur von **ſ** und **s**, und hat mit dem Beta nun mal gar nichts zu tun. Meiner Meinung nach störst du dich daran zurecht.

Sollte **ß** mal nicht verfügbar sein, soll **ss** benutzt werden - so ist es genormt und üblich.

Ich habe ähnliche Tendenzen manchmal im Polnischen beobachtet, wo man statt **Ł** das Pfund-Symbol **£** nutzt - furchtbar! (wobei das Polnische über keine solche Fallback-Lösung wie das *ss* für *ß* verfügt, also irgendwie ist der Reiz für derartige "kreativen Provisorien" größer)

Comment: *Das Eszett entstand als Ligatur von **ſ** und **s*** – Das ist zumindest irreführend. In gebrochenen Schriften entstand das Eszett in der Tat aus einer Ligatur, aber von *ſ* und *z.* In der Antiqua wurde das Eszett erst um die Wende zum 20. Jahrhundert eingeführt, erwuchs aber nicht aus einer Ligatur, sondern wurde direkt so in die Welt gesetzt (die Gestaltung war aber teilweise an alte *ſs*-Ligaturen angelehnt).

Comment: Danke für die Korrektur, ich war mir nicht sicher, ob es nun *s* oder *z* war. An der Kernaussage, dass ß mit β nichts zu tun hat, ändert das aber nichts.

Comment: **ß** heißt Eszett, nicht Eses... Natürlich sind es **ſ** und **z** und nicht **ſ** und **s**....

Comment: Vollkommen richrig, @adjan

Answer (score 5):

Es ist offensichtlich falsch (im Gegensatz zu *oe*). Alles darüber hinaus ist „primarily opinion based“.

Andere Alternativen wären übrigens *genie3en* und *genie\3en*. Ich weiß nicht, wie gelassen Du auf diese reagieren würdest.